# CLR hosting from managed code?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, clr-hosting

Is it possible to do some **CLR hosting** from a managed application?

As the hosting API is exposed through **COM** the plumbing should be possible.

Moreover, from the 4.0 version of the runtime, it's possible to **host more than one CLR in the same process**.

But I'm not sure about bootstrapping a CLR from another CLR; if possible in a way as simple as the bootstrapping from native C++, without using any unmanaged code.

Any pointer is welcome, thanks.

Comment: Have you checked if app domains could help achieve the same goal as you try to achieve with CLR hosting?

Comment: may I ask you why do you need this? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Is something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19513/Dynamic-But-Fast-The-Tale-of-Three-Monkeys-A-Wolf) what you're looking for?

Comment: @dtb: this is purely educational. :)

Comment: @VladL: same remark. :)

Comment: @ispiro: thanks for the link, really interesting, but not what I need here. :)

Answer (score 3):

Limited hosting support is provided for managed code via **System.AppDomainManager** class. This way, you can customize some CLR behavior, such as AppDomainCreation or Security, using only C# code.

Jeffrey Richter briefly talks about this in his book CLR via C#. http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/csharp/9780735639959/clr-hosting-and-appdomains/advanced_host_control

Check the msdn page for AppDomainManager 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainmanager(v=vs.110).aspx

Some other links with useful info: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/11/12/256550.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/11/17/259105.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. AppDomainManager indeed offers some control over runtime behavior. But I was more interested in threads control, e.g. with timeouts, to illustrate the use of CER. I've finally used a native C++ host. Anyway +1 :)